# Android: How to filter android phones by max texture size

Tags: android, opengl-es, filter, textures, manifest

I want to use multiple APK for my android App. I have a textures grouped by size (1024x1024, 2048x2048, 4096x4096). I know that every device has a limitation for max texture size and now I filter textures in runtime. The problem is that users whom have a crappy phones need to download all textures (even 4096x4096) so my app has a very big size. Is it a way to filter devices by max texture sizes in android manifest? Or is any woraround for this?

Comment: can you describe how you are downloading the textures?

Comment: I'm using AssetManager class available in libgdx. There is a method: _assetManager.get("assetName.jpg", Texture.class);

Comment: So they are bundled with the apk?

Comment: Yes, they are bundled with apk

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a way to filter devices by max texture sizes in android manifest?

Sorry, there aren't any filters you can add.

> Or is any workaround for this?

Since the assets are already bundled in the apk, you cannot delete them from the assets folder as they are read only. See "Files in assets/ are not given a resource ID, so you can read them only using AssetManager." from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

You could make your app/game download the appropriate texture pack when the app first starts up.

Comment: I can make 3 android projects - each one with different assets, but I don't know how to filter them. Is there any combination of screen-size and screen-density attributes to match GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE?

Comment: Nope,  as far as I can tell, the max texture size is comes from  the graphics chip on the device.  And there is no way to segment apks by them.  In terms of making three projects,..really you only need two. 4096px & 2048px as a 2048x2048 texture will work on every android device.  4096 will only work on those that have the newer better graphic chips.

Comment: I've read that some old devices has 1024 max texture size. Is that true?

Comment: Perhaps some really really old devices (g1),  but every device android 2.1+ is closer to 2048 or higher.